creating storage replica issue
i am trying to create a failover cluster with active/passive configuration.
and currently i am using two virtual machines on laptop for this.
as i don't have iSCSI, so i am trying to use storage replica for this.
i already have installed the storage replica feature, but when i try to exec the following powershell command to prepare for SRpartnership
New-SRGroup -ComputerName WIN-cname -Name SourceRG -VolumeName E: -LogVolumeName C:

i get the following error
    New-SRGroup : Unable to create replication group SourceRG, detailed reason: The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SRGroup -ComputerName "WIN-cname" -Name "SourceRG" -VolumeN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_WvrAdminTasks:root/Microsoft/...T_WvrAdminTasks) [New-SRGroup], Ci
   mException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 3,New-SRGroup

despite that i can navigate to the driver and i can get the volume information through
get-volume

and also, i can create files there, so there is no privileges issues.
note: the volume i am trying to use is created from a shrinked volume.
i would appreciate your help.

Does drive E: exist on the remote computer?

yes, and isn't the command get executed locally ?

Is WIN-cname the name of your local computer?

yea, i changed for the post, but i use the name of the local computer

Ok, then in that case you can leave it out all together, because when not given, the ComputerName  parameter defaults to the local computer

there was a network issue between the two nodes, but after fixing the issue of the network between the two nodes, the driver appeared and now i can use it.
i don't know if that is true or not, but i think the failover cluster was reserving the disk as a resource for the cluster.
